# Expectation of $B_u \operatorname{argmax}_t B_t$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

*This question is a [repost from math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4883793/1132955). The question turned out to be harder than I initially thought, so I decided to try my luck here.*

---

Yesterday I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4883217/1132955) about the joint law of $(M_T, B_u)$, where $M_T = \max_{t \in [0, T]} B_t$, $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion and $u < T$.

One of the reasons I was interested in this law is because I needed to compute $\mathbb{E} \{ \tau B_u \}$, where $\tau$ is the a.s. unique point at which the maximum $M_T$ is attained: $M_T = B_\tau$.

Knowing the joint law $(M_T, B_u)$, it is possible to find the joint law of $(\tau, B_u)$ as follows: for $u > t$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P} \{ \tau > t, \ B_u < x \}
& = \mathbb{P} \{ \sup_{s \in [0, t]} B_s < B_t + \sup_{s \in [t, T]} ( B_s - B_t ), B_t + ( B_u - B_t) < x \} \\[7pt]
& = \mathbb{P} \{ M_t - B_t < M_{T-t}^*, B_t + B_{u-t}^* < x \} \\[7pt]
& = \int \mathbb{1} \{ Y - y < Z, y + z < x \} \cdot
\mathbb{P} \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
& B_t \in dy \\
& M_t \in dY
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\cdot
\mathbb{P} \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
& B_{u-t}^* \in dz \\
& M_{T-t}^* \in dZ
\end{aligned}
\right\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
It then remains to plug in the well-known formula for the density of $(B_t, M_t)$ and the density of $(B_{u-t}^*, B_{T-t}^*)$ found in my previous quesion.

All this is doable *in principle*, but in practice this is a very heavy computation. Which brings me to my new question: **is there a simpler way to compute $\mathbb{E}\{ \tau B_u \}$?** Without going through the hard labour of finding the joint pdf of $(\tau, B_u)$.

Maybe there is a trick I do not see?

---

P.S. A closely related quantity, if I made no mistake, is $\mathbb{E} \{ M_T \, B_u \, B_v \}$. Using Malliavin integration by parts formula, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \{ M_T \, B_u \, B_v \}
& = \mathbb{E} \left\{ M_T \, B_u \, \int_0^T \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [0, v] \} dB_s \right\} \\
& = \mathbb{E} \left \{ \int_0^T D_s ( M_T \, B_u ) \, \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [ 0, v ] \} ds \right\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $D_s M_T = \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [0, \tau] \}$ and $D_s B_u = \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [0, u] \}$, applying the chain rule we get
$$
D_s ( M_T \, B_u ) = \mathbb{1} \{s \in [0, \tau]\} \, B_u + M_T \, \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [0, u] \}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \{ M_T \, B_u \, B_v \}
& = \mathbb{E} \left\{ B_u \int_0^T \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [0, \tau \wedge v] \} ds \right\}
+\mathbb{E} \left\{ M_T \int_0^T \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [0, u \wedge v] ds \right\}
\\
& = \mathbb{E} \{ ( \tau \wedge v ) B_u \}
+(u \wedge v) \mathbb{E} \{ M_T \}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now $\mathbb{E} \{ M_T \}$ is known and the problem of finding $\mathbb{E} \{ ( \tau \wedge v ) B_u \}$ seems similar to the problem of finding $\mathbb{E} \{ \tau B_u \}$.

Unfortunately, the problem of finding $\mathbb{E} \{ M_T \, B_u \, B_v \}$ is as hard as the problem of finding $\mathbb{E} \{ \tau B_u \}$. In my previous question I managed to come near the formula for the joint law of $(M_T, B_u, B_v)$, but applying it wouldn't be easy.