# A question about one Malliavin derivative calculation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, gaussian

Recently, I've asked here [a question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467352/496689). While trying to find an answer on my own, I found an idea which I now will briefly describe below. *I am not familiar enough with the Malliavin calculus*, so my question here is this: **is this calculation correct?** Did I by any chance miss some crucial assumptions for this to hold or misunderstood something?

The idea is this. I am trying to calculate
$$
f(u, v) = \mathbb{E} \{ F \cdot ( B_u B_v - u \wedge v) \}
$$
for some random variable $F \in L^2 ( \Omega, \mathcal{F}_T, P)$ and $B_t$ the standard Brownian motion. By Theorem 2.9.1 from Nualart's *Introduction to Malliavin calculus*, there exists an adapted process $X_s$ such that
$$
F = \mathbb{E} \{ F \} + \int_0^T X_s \, dB_s.
$$
Then, since
$$
\mathbb{E} \{ B_u B_v - u \wedge v \} = 0,
$$
we have
$$
f ( u, v) = \mathbb{E} \left\{ \int_0^T X_s \, d B_s \cdot \Big[ B_u B_v - u \wedge v \Big] \right\}.
$$
Applying Malliavin integration by parts formula, we get
$$
f ( u, v ) = \mathbb{E} \left\{
\int_0^T X_s \, D_s \Big[ B_u B_v - u \wedge v \Big] \, ds
\right\}.
$$
The derivative is easy to compute since $D_s B_u = \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [0, u] \}$ and $D_s ( \text{non-random function} ) = 0$. Hence,
$$
f ( u, v ) = \mathbb{E} \left\{
B_u \cdot \int_0^T X_s \, \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [ 0, v ] \} \, ds
\right\}
+ \mathbb{E} \left\{
B_v \cdot \int_0^T X_s \, \mathbb{1} \{ s \in [ 0, u ] \} \, ds
\right\}.
$$
To simplify the latter, let us use Malliavin integration by parts again with $B_u = \int_0^T \mathbb{1} \{ t \in [0, u] \} \, dB_t$:
$$
f ( u, v ) = \mathbb{E} \left\{
\int_0^u dt \, \int_0^v ds \, D_t X_s
\right\}
+ \mathbb{E} \left\{
\int_0^v dt \, \int_0^u ds \, D_t X_s
\right\}.
$$
Therefore, we have finally obtained
$$
\boxed{
f ( u, v ) = \int_0^u dt \, \int_0^v ds \, \mathbb{E} \{ D_t X_s + D_s X_t \}.
}
$$

It seems to me that the only assumption I've used is the existence of $D_t X_s$. Is this true?